# Waiting for network configuration error

Tags: networking

When  I  want  to  login into  my Ubuntu System, it  appears

> waiting  for  network  configuration

and the  second  is

> waiting  for  more 60  seconds

then it appear when we  use  the  common <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> the  Screen  System, which  caused  the  problem  I  think is  I can't connect to the  Internet.

So  I   changed  something  in `/etc/network/`, but now  I  want  to  it  go back  to the  original  the  network configuration,  but  I  don't know  what  to  do.

Anyone  can  help?
Can anyone  give  detailed answers?

Thank  you

Comment: What file did you alter in /etc/network, and can you edit your post to include the contents of that file please?

Comment: maybe  the   /etc/network/interfaces   ,i,m  not  sure,so  do  your  know  the  answers

Comment: Please put your `/etc/network/interfaces` inside your question so we can help.

Comment: for  you  advise,so  I  gives  the  network   configuration  as   follows:                                                            #interfaces(5) file used by  ifup(8) and  if down(8)                 auto  lo#                                                           iface lo inet loopback                                           auto  eth0                                                        iface  etho  inet  dhcp                                           auto eth0                                                              I have  Omission  some   comment

Answer (score 1):

If you edited your `/etc/network/interfaces` file and want to return to a default Server config, try this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

This assumes that you are getting an IP address from DHCP on the `eth0` (primary) Ethernet interface.

Comment: it  dint  work,   so  do  you  have  any  solution  for  this  problem

Comment: Not without more information from you about what changes you made that caused the problem.

Comment: so  can  you  tell  me  how  to  solve  the  problem

Comment: Run `ifconfig` and post the contents of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file
sudo nano /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf

Go to the line;
start on (filesystem and static-network-up) or failsafe-boot

Change to;
start on (filesystem) or failsafe-boot

Than restart..